# Pull to refresh functionality isn't working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've put the code below in, and it looks close but I can't figure out why it's not doing the actual refresh.  It has the "Pull to refresh" and the updated text displaying properly, but it's not updating the actual data.  Am I missing something obvious, or do I have it misplaced or something?

I edited to add the self tableview call to reload the data.  Still no luck.

FINAL EDIT___User below solved it with calling the data feed.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

UIRefreshControl *refresh = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull to refresh"];
[refresh addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshmytable:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.refreshControl = refresh;

NSURLSessionConfiguration *config =
[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

_session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config
                                         delegate:self
            //   delegate:nil
                                    delegateQueue:nil];

[self fetchFeed];



}

- (void)refreshmytable:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl{

[self fetchFeed]; //Added 12:12 9.16.14
refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Updating"];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, h:mm a"];
NSString *updated = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Last Update: %@", [formatter     stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:updated];
                                  [refreshControl endRefreshing];

[self.tableView reloadData]; //Added this 11:32 9.16.14

}





- (void)fetchFeed
{
 NSString *userEID = MAP_getUsername();
 //NSLog(userEID);

 NSString *requestString1 = [@"URL" stringByAppendingString:userEID];

 NSString *requestString2 = @"&status=pending";

 NSString *requestString = [requestString1 stringByAppendingString:requestString2];

 //NSLog(requestString);

 /*NSString *requestString = @"http://URL";
*/
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask =
[self.session dataTaskWithRequest:req
                completionHandler:
 ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {


     NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                options:0
                                                                 error:nil];
     self.changeList = jsonObject[@"List"];
     //self.changeList=nil; //tried to add here to remove duplicate data

     NSLog(@"%@", self.changeList);

     //- add code here to populate BNRItemStore with the change order list.
     // - following code should be rewritten in fetchFeed that will load BNRItemStore.
     if (self.changeList.count>0) {
         for (int i = 0; i < self.changeList.count; i++) {
             NSDictionary *coItem = self.changeList[i];

             [[BNRItemStore sharedStore]
              addItemWithApproverEid:coItem[@"approverEid"]
              assignmentGroup:coItem[@"assignmentGroup"]
              changeOrder:coItem[@"changeOrder"]
              subcategory:coItem[@"subCatagory"]
              title:coItem[@"title"]


              ];
         }
     }
     //NSLog(@"sizeof(NSInteger) = %@", @(sizeof(NSInteger)));
     //- end comment

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
     });
     //self.changeList=nil; //trying to null out list for refresh non duplicate data


   //  NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   //  NSLog(@"%@", json);
 }];


[dataTask resume];
}
```

Comment: Which code in your `refreshmytable:` method is gathering new data and telling the table to update with it?

Comment: I added the edit above.  Still no luck though.  It looks like it runs, but again the data stays the same.

Comment: @JamesCockerham, make sure you are setting the data structure that is holding your feeds to nil before filling it with new data.  Also, mark the answer correct if it helped and answered your question.  People don't help if you ask and don't confirm answers.

Comment: Thanks for the help bdparrish.  Logically, where do I put the nil for the dataset?

Comment: you can put it inside the fetchFeed method after a successful fetch on the feeds and before adding your fetched feeds to the array or whatever data structure you are adding it to.

Comment: I added my fetch feed code above.  I put it in comments where I tried to nil out the list, and neither were good.  Is there somewhere else it should go?

Comment: It looks like I'm getting Null on the data in the structure, but it's still displaying double.  Is there a way to wipe the display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not fetching the new data.  You have a method/message call `fetchFeed` that you call in the `viewDidLoad` but you never call it in the refresh method/message.  I assume that if you refresh, then you need to fetch new data.  Call `[self fetchFeed];' before reloading the table view.  If you are fetch the data asynchronously, then you need to have the table view reload in the completion block when fetching the new data is complete.

Comment: Just realized that now I'm getting duplicate data.  Can you tell me if I placed it properly above?

Comment: @JamesCockerham, see comment in original post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call to `reloadData` somewhere in `refreshmytable` method for the table view to update the data

```
- (void)refreshmytable:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl{
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Updating"];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, h:mm a"];
    NSString *updated = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Last Update: %@", [formatter     stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:updated];
                              [refreshControl endRefreshing];
    [self.tableView reloadData]
```

}